# How to create A windows form application (.exe) linked to the SQL server, and having an Approval Function (PDF/PNG, Stamping approval)

Tags: c#, file-upload, server, download

Many thanks @Mirko for the reply and comment. So sorry if im not clear myself.
I'll try to make it alot more understandable.

- First thing is, I want to create an application for a Data Entry Form on Windows (Windows Form Application .exe). This application required database
  and for a database server im thinking about SQL (Need some advise  here on the server).
- After the Form-Design completed and linked to the database, i want it to be able accessing PDF/PNG and stamping also, For approval purpose. Thus i need some file transfer server for this and some new coding line for this function. (I need a lot of help here especially the coding line).

Please note i've also tried making a form-based application on VBA Excel and use it's sheets for the database. But im struggling on how to make an access for File transfering and stamping (Approval) protocol. Thus lead me to C# on Visual Studio, hoping this coding program could handle such file-embed system.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nico, I am not sure this will make a great SO question. Sorry, I cannot provide this detailed feedback in comments as they do not allow enough text. You are asking for advice that is in my opinion too broad. Meaning you really have many considerations here and are in essence asking (I think) how do I build a document management and approval (workflow) application.

You may want to look into document management solutions (I am no expert on those), but many handle approval flows and meta-data on documents well.

I would recommend you carefully consider even your starting assumptions. In my opinion if you are building a green-field application now you should decide between WPF (instead of Windows Forms) and a Web Application (that is in the .NET space) and I would probably recommend ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. If more than one person will use this application I would lean towards the latter strongly as it is more easily accessed and updated.

I am not the best person to answer how to do the Stamping approval part, but you may want to consider either an existing document management solution (maybe DocuSign, etc. as an integration) as they may offer you the features you are looking for out of the box. If not take a look at PDF libraries in the .NET space (I personally used Aspose in the past, but they tend to be expensive).

If you are looking to track metadata about the documents to be uploaded/approved SQL server is often a good choice, but since you are quite literally seeming to aim for document management, more document-centric options maybe a good fit (MongoDB, Cosmos (Azure), DocumentDB (AWS), ...) as they allow you to store arbitrary meta-data.

Comment: Okaay i've made an update for this request, many thanks for the feedback @Mirko

Comment: This is trully appreciated @Mirko. I do also had some thoughts on Azure Service, and currently trying to understand the different between WinForm and WPF. I found some good explanation regarding this WPF thing, probabbly im gonna go with your advise by using WPF instead. Many many thanks for this help. and About the Document Management approval (Workflow) i've figured how to "Trick" this issue a little bit ...so i dont need a stamp on the Files. Once again thanks.